# Webkit-flex not rendering on react children component in next.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components, next.js, react-component

Here's the two different methods that gives different css results on next.js rendering from styled-components:

index.js:

```
return (
// list the children
{data.map((item, key) => (
 <ParentComp key={key || "0"}>
   <ChildComp data={item} />
</ParentComp>
//...
```

compared to:

```
return (
// state each children
<ParentComp>
    <ChildComp/>
    <ChildComp/>
</ParentComp>
//...
```

will render different css I see on developer console:

```
/* when the children is listed */
.ParentComp {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-start;
}

.ChildComp {
min-height: 400px;
width: 264px;
flex: 0 0 264px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

compared to:

```
/* when each children is stated (the intended one) */
.ParentComp {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-items: flex-start;
-webkit-box-align: flex-start;
-ms-flex-align: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start;

.ChildComp {
-webkit-flex: 0 0 264px;
-ms-flex: 0 0 264px;
flex: 0 0 264px;
margin: 5px;
min-height: 400px;
width: 264px;
}
```

Even though they're from the same`styled-component`'s component (`ParentComp` and `ChildComp`), consisting the same code, thus the same behaviour is expected on the browser (they're not).

Of course I can override fully the intended css result to the `styled-component`'s component and the problem solved, but nonetheless this thing puzzles me on which part is to blame (next.js/styled-component/or even bulma-styled-components I use) and the solution is not practical (copying full css rendering result).

Does anyone has a glimpse of clue on this? Thanks.

**Update:**

Problem is still not solved even after copied to styled-components' component, I'll try to make a minimal repo on this.

**Update II:**

Here's the minimal repo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wqoxjq31wl

You can try to change `eachComp` to `listComp` at the editor `index.js` to know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

My bad...

It should be like this:

```
        <ParentComp >
        {data.map((item, key) => (
          <ChildComp key={key || "0"} data={item} />
          ))}
        </ParentComp >
```